# Why can't -z be the last command-line option to be used with tar?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar, flag

```
$ ls one.tar.gz
one.tar.gz
$ tar -xvfz one.tar.gz
tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
$ tar -xvzf one.tar.gz
one
$ tar -xzvf one.tar.gz
one
$ tar -zxvf one.tar.gz
one
$
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `-f` switch takes an argument (the filename). If `z` appears after the `f` then it is taken to be the filename.

```
tar -xvfz one.tar.gz
```

is the same as

```
tar -xvf z one.tar.gz
```

If you had done this:

```
tar -xvf -z one.tar.gz
```

then `-z` would have been taken as the filename and you'd have gotten a similar error.

This, however, would have worked:

```
tar -xvz -f one.tar.gz
```

The [GNU `tar` man page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/tar.1.php) states:

> The first argument to tar must be one of the options: Acdrtux, followed by any optional functions. The final arguments to tar are the names of the files or directories which should be archived.

Note that unless input is from stdin or output is to stdout (where appropriate), the the `-f filename` option and argument must be given. While the man page implies that the order is fixed, in reality the options can be in any order. Even this weird one works (but it may not work in all versions of `tar`):

```
tar -v files_to_archive* -f xyz.tar.gz -cz
```

For portability, it's probably better to stick to the idiomatic argument order and even leave off the hyphen:

```
tar czvf xyz.tar.gz files_to_archive*
```

Comment: z being last and f taking an argument are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: That's true, but I didn't say that. Perhaps I should have been more explicit and said "immediately after".

Comment: You didn't say it, but you did begin your sentence with "because", which is an affirmation of his question, which claims z cannot be last, thereby indirectly implying that z cannot be last. Anyway, I am being pedantic. If you remove "because" then your answer is improved IMO.

Comment: Pedantic, yes. I took the question to include an implied "in this sequence". Most of the time with `tar` you see all the switches concatenated rather than separated as you have in your answer. There's no reason a person couldn't do it the way you show, but the idiom is to do it the way it's shown in the first two successful examples in the question: `<operation> <option> <option> <file>`. The idiom leads to the inference.

Answer (score 6):

**z** can be used last:

```
tar -x -v -f foo.tar.gz  -z
```

But as stated by @Dennis, the **f** flag takes an argument.